radical of an ideal as intersection of ideals
I am trying to follow the proof, that $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}=\cap_{p\in Z(\mathfrak{a})}p$. I saw the question here before answered by @kobe (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1948848), but i dont understand why it suffices to show that the maximal element $\mathfrak{p}\in\Omega$ is prime. I thought that this would imply
\begin{equation}
x^n\in \mathfrak{p}\implies x\in \mathfrak{p};\;x\notin \mathfrak{p}\implies x^n\notin\mathfrak{p},
\end{equation}
but we want to show that
\begin{equation}
x\notin\mathfrak{p}.
\end{equation}
Maybe someone can help me to see why this is enough? Happy for every help!

For ease of typing let me use home letters instead of mathfrak. We want to show $\cap_{P\supseteq A, P\text{ prime}} P\subseteq \sqrt A$. The answer linked proved by selecting an element $x$ not in $\sqrt A$, and constructed a prime ideal containing $A$ but does not contain $x$, which implies $x\notin \cap_{P\supseteq A, P\text{ prime}} P$

Omg yes, seems like i almost forgot what i wanted to prove haha. So obvious and kind of embarrasing, thank you so much!!

@Asigan This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, but I thought the question might be marked duplicate. Therefore I only commented instead of answering.
